# Unable to run localhost:3000 in node.js app, Error: Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory "./views"

Tags: node.js, express, localhost

I'm trying to display my nodejs app via localhost:3000.

My main JS file is "app.js". I ran in the terminal this: "node app" and the response was "server run", but **when I type "localhost:3000" in my browser, the terminal shows this error message: "Error: Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory "C:...\views".** Then I ran in the terminal "npm start", and got the same response of "server run", and then the same localhost:3000 browser error: "Error: Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory "C:...\views".

I installed those packages:
(1) npm init y-, THEN package.json, (2) express-handlebars (and added views\main.handlebar + views\home.handlebars files).

My code in the file **app.js** is the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home', { title: 'Home Page' });
});

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.render('about', { title: 'About Us Page' });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server run!'));
```

[This is the printscreen that maybe will help more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST4Iv.jpg)

Looking up in questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480227/failed-to-lookup-view-error-in-views-directory), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58583570/failed-to-lookup-view-index-in-views-directory-home-ubuntu-weather-app-views) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59579460/error-failed-to-lookup-view-index-in-views-directory-views) didn't help me to solve my problem.
What should L do to fix in and make localhost:3000 run properly in my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `home.handlebars` file in the wrong folder.

As you can see from the error message, it is expected to be found as `views/home.handlebars`, however you have it in `views/layouts/home.handlebars`!

The `views/layouts` folder should contain only layouts (such as your `main.handlebars` which is apparently configured as layout).

(I guess the `about.handlebars` file should go in `views` as well...)

[image]

It should look like this instead:

[image]

Comment: Not sure. look at row 5 of app.js, It says: app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));....
The full address is: Error: Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory "C:\nodeJS\nodejs book\three\views"....
If I move the home and\or the main file outside of the layout folder to the views folder, I get in my browser this error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodeJS\nodejs book\three\views\layouts\main.handlebars'

Comment: When I left just "main.handlebars" in views\layouts folder, and moved the home & about files out to views folder, it works fine. is this the right solution?

Comment: Yes this is what I showed above. `main` is a layout (you set it as `defaultLayout`), so it goes into `views/layouts`. `home` and `about` are regular views, they go in `views`.

Comment: If this solution works for you, you can mark the answer as accepted, marking the question as solved. Thank you!